# XSLT: Access Java object properties / methods in for-each

Tags: java, arrays, xslt

So i have an array of some Java objects:

```
SomeElementsArray[]
```

and I am trying to access the properties of each object in an XSLT stylesheet file, like this:

```
<xsl:for-each select="//data/SomeElementsArray">
 <xsl:variable name="dto" select="current()" />
  <block>
    <xsl:value-of select="someObjectAttribute" />
  </block>
</xsl:for-each>
```

The problem is that I tried in many ways ti get something, but I get no result. If I just output the `$dto` variable I get the reference to the object, like this:

```
[Lcom.domain.core.model.SomeElements;@3f38dd0
```

I am using a number of variables to this XSLT as a Map called 'data'(`Map<String, Object> data = new HashMap<String, Object>();`) . For example, I can access 'data/something' and it shows what it should show and this array is mapped in '`data/SomeElementsArray`'.

What am I doing wrong? All the fields of the objects in the array are public and I also have getters and setters....Please help!

Comment: You need to tell us which XSLT processor you are using. Conventions for accessing Java objects vary from one to another.

Comment: I didn't ask which XSLT version, I asked which processor: e.g. Xalan, Saxon, IBM Websphere, Oracle XDK, MarkLogic, Altova. They are all different when it comes to vendor extensions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the solution:

1. First, the value in the Map cannot be any type of objects. XSLT (at least the version I am using - 1.0) supports only primitive values (i.e. String, int, boolean, Nodes, etc). It cannot be the type of the array I am passing (i.e. SomeElementsArray[]). In some way, the value has to be brought to the primitives.
2. In order to pass that array, custom transformation has to be done, meaning that for types like HashMaps, ArrayLists, etc. I need to write some code that generates the XML/XSLT nodes. For example, here is some code that does the transformations recursively:

   ```
   private static void field(StringBuilder builder, String tag, Object content) {
       if(content == null) {
           return;
       } else if(content instanceof Iterable) {
           for(Object object: (Iterable) content) {
               field(builder, tag, object);
       }
       return;
   } else if(content.getClass().isArray() && !(content instanceof  Map)) {
       for(int i = 0; i < Array.getLength(content); i++) {
           field(builder, tag, Array.get(content, i));
       }
       return;
   }
   if(content instanceof Double || content instanceof Float) content = String.format("%.2f", content);
   if(content instanceof Date) content = dateFormat.format(content);
   if(content instanceof Calendar) content = dateFormat.format(new Date(((Calendar) content).  getTimeInMillis()));
   builder.append("<");
   builder.append(tag);
   builder.append(">");
   if(content instanceof Map) {
       Map map = (Map) content;
       for(Object object: map.entrySet()) {
           Map.Entry entry = (Map.Entry) object;
           field(builder, (String) entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
       }
   } else {
       try { //making sure that characters are decoded in case they
           //are encoded
           content = URLDecoder.decode(content.toString(), "UTF-8");
       } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
           //silently ignores error
           //and content will be untouched
       }
       String value = content.toString().
               replace("&", "&amp;").
               replace("<", "&lt;").
               replace(">", "&gt;").
               replace("'", "&apos;").
               replace("\"", "&quot;");
       builder.append(value);
   }
   builder.append("</");
   builder.append(tag);
   builder.append(">");}
   ```

Basically, the transformation above allows any type of values in the Map, so it is possible now to have `Map<String, ArrayList<Map<String, Map<String, Map<String, String>>>>` with no issues. The XML is being written like this:

```
public static void write(String stylesheetText, Map<String, ?> input, OutputStream output) {
    StringBuilder xml = new StringBuilder();
    xml.append("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n\n");
    xml.append("<data>");
    for(Map.Entry<String, ?> entry: input.entrySet()) {
        field(xml, entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
    }
    xml.append("</data>");
    FopFactory fopFactory = FopFactory.newInstance();
    FOUserAgent foUserAgent = fopFactory.newFOUserAgent();
    try {
        TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        StreamSource source = new StreamSource(new StringReader(stylesheetText));
        Transformer transformer = factory.newTransformer(source);
        transformer.setParameter("versionParam", "2.0");
        Source s = new StreamSource(new StringReader(xml.toString()));
        Fop fop = fopFactory.newFop(MimeConstants.MIME_PDF, foUserAgent, output);
        Result result = new SAXResult(fop.getDefaultHandler());
        transformer.transform(s, result);
        output.close();
    } catch (IOException exception) {
        throw new PdfException(exception);
    } catch (TransformerException exception) {
        throw new PdfException(exception);
    } catch (TransformerFactoryConfigurationError exception) {
        throw new PdfException(exception);
    } catch (FOPException exception) {
        throw new PdfException(exception);
    }
}
```

3. Having point 1 and 2 in mind, the looping can be done like in the question, with no problem.

In my case, "SomeElementsArray" is an `ArrayList<Map<String, String>>` for simplicity. It can be a Map as well, but then every child root node will have a unique name, so additional parsing must be done.

I hope this helps someone someday, as I learned this in the hard way.